# magento 2 data migration : Integrity Check failed

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2-migration-tool

i did setup of magento 2 i all wen well i started data migration using below command :

```
php /var/www/html/bin/magento migrate:data --reset etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.4/config.xml
```

now it stopped with error

- Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_order. Fields:
  adj_sku,adj_product

Can you please guide what to do to fix it

Comment: check my answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233476/need-help-in-magento2-data-migration/262983#262983][1]