# Need help in magento2 Data migration

Tags: migration, magento2-migration-tool

I followed the below link for data migration.

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/migrate-from-magento-1-to-magento-2/

Once i run below command i am getting

php bin/magento migrate:data --reset < path to your config.xml > --- replaced the path for my m1 version that is 1.9.0.1.

[Migration\Exception]

Integrity Check failed

error. Can anyone suggest please? What is the cause for this?

in config.xml i added the below code.

```
 <source>
    <database host="host-name" name="db-name" user="user-name" password="password" />
</source>
<destination>
    <database host="host-name" name="db-name" user="user-name" password="password" />
</destination>
<options>
<crypt_key>crypt-key</crypt_key>
</options>
```

Here is the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Did you migrate setting?

Comment: Yes, 
php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset <path to your config.xml>
that's shown completed.

Comment: What is the exception are you getting?

Comment: php -d memory_limit=10G bin/magento migrate:data -r -a  path to your config.xml > Try this it should work but you will get warning and errors but still data will be migrated to your system. Afterwards you need to fix those errors and warnings one by one.

Comment: I tried above command with memory_limit ,  same again. what i got previously same error. I have attached the screenshot.

Comment: Used -a with -r then i got below error.
SQLSTATE[08S01]: Communication link failure: 1153 Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80116/discussion-between-jafar-and-sukumar-gorai).

Comment: hi @SukumarGorai, can we migrate only customers and orders?

Comment: @SukumarGorai, I am getting below error when migration process starts,
 Notice: Undefined offset: 9 vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\src\Migration\Step\Eav\Data.php on line 292

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the documents and fields that are shown in the error message (in red) to the ignore list.

For more details on how to do this, check https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-internal-spec.html

Comment: hi @Anshu Mishra, can we migrate only customers and orders?

Comment: @jafarpinjar Yes

Comment: I have migrated all data successfully, now i need to migrate latest orders n customers, can you provide me the steps please how to migrate only customers n order?

Comment: hi @Anshu mishra, I am getting below error.

  Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\src\Migration\Step\Eav\Data.php on line 292

Comment: IN which file do i need to turn off? I am migrating data from 1.9 to 2.3, ce-ce version

Comment: @jafarpinjar The issue seems to be because of some corrupted data or invalid data in eav attribute.

Comment: okay fine, how to resolve this type of errors?
have you migrated data successfully ?

Comment: @jafarpinjar Yes, I have migrated data successfully. You need to check your database. Check all the {entity}_eav_attribute tables and find all the unique attribute_id and compare with all the unique attribute_id in eav_attribute table. You may any extra attribute id in any of the {entity}_eav_attribute. First check for attribute_id 9.

Comment: Chekc your database, is new m2 database? First check for attribute_id 9. in which table?

Comment: @jafarpinjar m1 db. first check in eav_attribute, then in the corresponding {entity}_eav_attribute