# Magento 2 migration issue || Integrity Check failed

Tags: magento2

I am facing this issue while migrating from `Magento1.9.2.2 to Magento2.3.0`. I am doing this in my localhost.

[image]

Comment: Check My Answer > https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233476/need-help-in-magento2-data-migration/262983#262983